# Functions-framework (emulator) subscribing to Pub/Sub emulator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, functions-framework

I want to make a setup: My Dockerized App -> Pub/Sub Dockerized emulator <- Cloud functions Dockerized emulator

In steps:

1. My app publishes a message to Pub/Sub Docker emulator
2. Pub/Sub Docker emulator registers a message under topic
3. Cloud function/s subscribe to the topic and process

I want to have run every service locally and test the whole setup first in the development mode. I successfully set up the first two parts. I'm able to publish a message to Dockerized emulator and also get the data by subscribing to it.

After this, I wanted to add Cloud Functions (step 3) and let function/s subscribe to that topic. I Dockerized functions as well and put everything to docker-compose file so I don't need to think about network, environment, or setup steps.

**My problem is that I don't know how to trigger the dockerized Cloud function when Pub/Sub emulator registers a new message.**

Docker images I use:

1. My app is dockerized node.js Express server
2. I am using [this image](https://github.com/marcelcorso/gcloud-pubsub-emulator) as my Pub/Sub emulator (it is simply Google's Pub/Sub emulator but dockerized). I can simply set topics and subscriptions via docker-compose file
3. I dockerized functions myself

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myapp:
    build: ./myapp
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST: pubsub:8681
      PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID: pubsubproject
    volumes:
        - ./myapp/:/workspace
        - /workspace/node_modules
    depends_on: 
    - pubsub

  pubsub:
    image: messagebird/gcloud-pubsub-emulator
    environment:
      PUBSUB_PROJECT1: 'pubsubproject,published-events:published-events-pull'
    ports:
      - "8681:8681"

  functions:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./functions
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    depends_on: 
      - pubsub
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST: pubsub:8681
      PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID: pubsubproject
    volumes:
      - ./functions/:/workspace
      - /workspace/node_modules
```

My app's code responsible for publishing (this works):

```
async publishToQueue(events: any[]) {
        const pubSub = new PubSub();
        const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(events))

        try {
            const messageId = await pubSub.topic("published-events").publish(buffer);
            console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Received error while publishing: ${error.message}`);
            process.exitCode = 1;
          }
    }
```

Cloud function's code (**The code in this function is never triggered**)

```
import { PubSub } from '@google-cloud/pubsub'

exports.helloPubSub = (data, context) => {   // <---- This function is never triggered
    console.log("FROM CLOUD FUNCTION")
    console.log(data)
    console.log(context)

    const pubSub = new PubSub()
    const subscription = pubSub.subscription("published-events-pull")

    const messageHandler = async message => {
        const data = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString())
        console.log('Received data:')
        console.log(data)
        message.ack()
    }
    subscription.on('message', messageHandler)
};
```

package.json script (what is called from Dockerfile to start the function). dist/ folder is specified because I use TypeScript.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "yarn run build:dev:init && yarn run build:dev | yarn run start:functions",
    "build:dev:init": "yarn run tsc ",
    "build:dev": "yarn run tsc -w ",
    "start:functions": "functions-framework --port=8888 --source=dist/ --target=helloPubSub --signature-type=event"
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I think people should have an option to test how multiple emulators communicate with each other and have a production-like feeling. I hope it is possible.

Comment: So far I have found out that if I remove --signature-type=event from scripts, run again, trigger URL once, then a new PubSub object in the function is created and then it listens to new messages from PubSub. But this is obviously wrong. Just wanted to note that there is no problem with the PubSub subscription but with triggering the function using the event.

Comment: The code in the function might be wrong, but my point is that the function is never triggered, just to be clear

Answer (score 1):

The `function` emulator code above needs to actually start the subscription to listen for messages from the Pub/Sub topic. Please note that Cloud Functions uses an underlying subscription to receive messages from Cloud Pub/Sub and trigger the user-defined function. Pub/Sub (and in this case the emulator) has no knowledge of any user-defined Cloud Functions.

To emulate this behavior, listen to messages from the Pub/Sub topic following this [example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/7b7d99603550fb2bdb3d33aba25b9258bfee1bcc/samples/listenForMessages.js#L66-L72)  and then invoke your desired user-defined function with constructed [`data` and `context`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#functions_background_parameters-nodejs) parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. So I should only use the example you linked whenever I do local development, right? I bet on production I don't need any listener since this is handled by GCP itself. Or am I wrong? Also, I found that there is this example in functions-framework's GitHub (it seems to be pretty new), although this one is a push method. Is the push method better when doing local development?  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/master/docs/events.md#using-the-pubsub-emulator

Comment: If you are using the functions-framework already, I would follow their advice and test using a push subscription. That way you would have to do the pulling in the application code and can test your implementation as it will run on GCF.

Comment: Alright, I will inform you later how it went. Thanks for now!

Comment: @MichalMoravik How'd it go?

Comment: @21rw If you use any serverless service (Cloud Run or Cloud Functions), you must use push subscription method, not pull. The link in my first comment above is therefore relevant. The package, @google-cloud/pubsub, will then send a POST request to the "pushEndpoint". Since all it does is sending a POST request, to test just one service/function, you can simply send a POST request using your HTTP client (Postman/Insomnia) that has the same structure as the message. I'll continue in the next comment ....

Comment: BUT if you need to test multiple services/functions, basically the whole pipeline, you need to emulate this behaviour. The code in the link then comes handy. You need to run the script so your emulator will register the destination (pushEndpoint) where to send the message in itself. In this case, you can make script that specifies multiple topics, subscriptions, etc. When the emulator is set, you can run the whole pipeline. The problem is, that you just set it for your locally run emulator. If you want to make it universal for every developer, you need to Dockerize your solution.

Comment: We (the company I work for) made our own Docker emulator similar to this one https://hub.docker.com/r/messagebird/gcloud-pubsub-emulator. Our version though is much better since it gives you an option to register both push and pull subscriptions while the one in the link only allows pull. I will talk to the team and ask when we plan to release it for the open-source community.

Comment: Hey, great! Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I also ended up creating an emulator in docker similar to that one, using the cloud sdk image.